# How to make my upvote/downvote button store cookies and count votes only 1 time

Tags: javascript, css, html

Take a look at this https://fiddle.jshell.net/tnvv0dds/4/ I made this upvote/downvote button for my website, but it resets every time I refresh the website and it counts votes every time I click on it. I have no idea how to fix it since I am a bit new. Can someone make a JavaScript suggestion for me? I spent 3-4 days in searching it without success.

Comment: please include how you tried to archive it with cookies.

Comment: you must store count in cookies or store it to database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can learn HTML5 [Web Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp), and use them with the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(localStorage.getItem("count") == null)
        $("#count").text(0);
    else
        $("#count").text(localStorage.getItem("count"));
});

var counter = 0;
$("#plus").click(function(){
  counter++;
  $("#count").text(counter);
  localStorage.setItem("count", counter);
});

$("#minus").click(function(){
  counter--;    
  $("#count").text(counter);
  localStorage.setItem("count", counter);
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot :D. Btw, can you also tell me, how to make votes count only 1 time?

Comment: I depends on what logic do you get.

Comment: Hey one problem. It store data, but when i cast another vote, it start from 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you want people to cast one vote each, you have to save the information of who voted how in a database on the server. This is the only way you can have a persistent count. Showing the current count, of course, involves querying the DB. Saving information into a database requires you using a server-sided programming language like e.g. PHP. **This cannot be done with pure client-sided JavaScript.**

To prevent people from double-voting, you can save their IP address on first vote and deny the vote whenever you find the current IP address in the database. Since some people have dynamic/changing IP addresses, this isn't bullet-proof. Additionally (really, only as an addition) you could save a flag in local storage or cookie and check that whenever a user tries to vote. Set flag on first vote and deny vote if flag was found.